# automating keyboard key press 9 times if alt key was pressed

Tags: bash, xdotool

I want to make an automation strategy, if I pressed the Alt key with any other key, it will simulate the keyboard key press 9 times for that key.

For example,
I press Alt + q, it will simulate pressing q 9 times. So for example if I was inside notepad, I will see

```
qqqqqqqqq
```

Now, most tutorials out there are showing how to reverse the output for that into a text file, for example by running

```
myScript.sh > out.txt
```

No, I don't want that. I want to run my script in the background, and use it anywhere inside my computer, anytime i press alt + any key, I see that key getting pressed 9 times.
This is useful in Games for example.

I tried the following, but it's not working. I don't see it detecting anything

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -rsn1 key < /dev/null

    # Check if Alt key is pressed (Escape sequence for Alt is "\e")
    if [[ "$key" == $'\e' ]]; then
        read -rsn1 key < /dev/null  # Read the next key

        # Check if Alt + alphabetical character was pressed (excluding 'z')
        if [[ "$key" =~ [a-y] ]]; then
            xdotool type --delay 100 "$key$key$key$key$key$key$key$key$key"
        fi
    fi
done
```

- I am running my script like:

```bash
$ chmod +x ./script.sh
$ ./script.sh &
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -rsn1 key < /dev/null

    # Check if Alt key is pressed (Escape sequence for Alt is "\e")
    if [[ "$key" == $'\e' ]]; then
        read -rsn1 key < /dev/null  # Read the next key

        # Check if Alt + alphabetical character was pressed (excluding 'z')
        if [[ "$key" =~ [a-y] ]]; then
            xdotool type --repeat=9 --delay=100 "$key"
        fi
    fi
done
```

You need `--repeat` for the number of presses.
You might need `xdotool keydown` if `type` doesn't have `--repeat`.

**Note:** You may want to target the specific window.
`window="$(xdotool getactivewindow)"`

Or, you can prompt the user to select: `xdotool selectwindow`